# JPA: lazy loading doesn't load even after the getter method is used. May it be?

Tags: java, jpa, proxy, persistence, lazy-loading

Can you simply explain me what means the phrase below:

> A relationship that is specified or defaulted to be lazily loaded
>   might or might not cause the related object to be loaded when the
>   getter method is used to access the object. The object might be a
>   proxy, so it might take actually invoking a method on it to cause it
>   to be faulted in. *(Pro JPA 2: Mastering the Java Persistence API, page 102)*

***My questions are:***

1. Does it mean that lazy_loaded_object might not be loaded even after the getLazyLoadedObj() method?
2. If the answer to the first question is 'YES', than what returns from the getLazyLoadedObj() method?
3. I still don't understand what will change if the lazy_loaded_object is the proxy. Please, explain it to me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes

2) A sub-class of the model object that has extra code in it to set up the properties when a getter is called.

3) You can imagine the object you get when calling, say, `getPerson()` to access a Lazily Loaded `PersonEntity` could look something like this:

```
public class LazyPersonEntity extends PersonEntity {

  private PersonEntity lazilyLoadedPerson;

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    if (lazilyLoadedPerson == null) {
      lazilyLoadedPerson = runQueryToLoadPerson();
    }
    return lazilyLoadedPerson.getName();
  }
}
```

Obviously that's not what the generated code really looks like, but functionally it's what's going on.  So when you do `getPerson()`  what you get is an instance of `LazyPersonEntity` and there is still no query until you call `getName()`

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I still don't understand the answer to the second question. What means 'subclass of the model object'. Does it means sub-class of the PersonEntity. But if it doesn't have any subclass?

Comment: The persistence provider framework creates the subclass at runtime.

Comment: But what contains that '**lazilyLoadedPerson** = runQueryToLoadPerson()' variable if there is still no query until you call getName()? Is it NULL?

Comment: and why there is need to create a sub-class. Why not just return a Person class?

Comment: Yes, it's null until you do something that causes it to load.  Because if you created a Person class, it would have to be filled-in with all the data from the database, not lazily loaded.  The sub-class lets the JPA stick in the extra code to run the query when the getter is called, so that it is able to wait until that time to query.

Comment: 'lazilyLoadedPerson = runQueryToLoadPerson();
if (lazilyLoadedPerson != null) {
  return lazilyLoadedPerson.getName();
}'
So is it a mistake?

Comment: That is not necessary, you are not allowed to lazy-load the person if it's possible for it to be null.  The Foreign Key must be guaranteed not-null.  The JPA provider will just ignore you if you tell it to try to lazy-load a nullable reference.

Comment: Yes. But you said that **lazilyLoadedPerson may be null** after 'lazilyLoadedPerson = runQueryToLoadPerson()'.

Comment: No, I said it's null before calling getName().  invoking the query is part of getName().  I'm sorry it's 4 in the morning here and I must go to bed, perhaps someone will happen along who can explain it differently.

Answer (score 6):

To answer 1) Yes. To understand 2) and 3) lets take an example

Lets say that you have a class `Parent` and it has `Child`. You define the `Child` to be loaded lazily.

```
class Parent {

  Child chil;

  //FetchMode = lazy
  public Child getChild() {
      return child;
  }

}
```

Lets say, you have loaded `Parent` instance already using hibernate session, say `parent`

Now when you call `parent.getChild();` the returning object can be an instance of `Child` or it could be a **Proxy**.

**What is a Proxy?**

Proxy are like **interceptors** to your class, A proxy for `Child` gets invoked *just before* any method of the `child` gets invoked..

For instance, when you invoke `child.getName()` --> lets say

`proxy.someProcessing()` method gets invoked
which internally invokes the `child.getName()`
and finally returns the data.

**Why we need proxy?**

The definition of lazy loading is **load when its required**. So just before `child.getName()` gets invoked by proxy, `proxy.someProcessing()` method calls the DB and gets the `CHILD` (DB Table mapped to `Child`) 's column data and loads the `child` object.

Comment: Do all entities in JPA contains inside the proxy class. Or it is a particular case?

Comment: most of the times lazy loaded entities will have the proxy class. In case of eager loading, proxy class may not be required.

Comment: But what contains that '**lazilyLoadedPerson** = runQueryToLoadPerson()' variable (**see the example below**) if there is still no query until you call getName()? Is it NULL?

Comment: "most of the times lazy loaded entities..." you mean, hibernate may not create a proxy for an entity? If so, could you tell me a situation in which hibernate doesn't create a proxy?(Except final getter or final class situation)